# My mod_rewrite code in htaccess caused the page to not load

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have horrible URLs like this:

http://example.com/subfolder/index.php?a=1&b=1&token=8d519decbe60db44154b1fbc8c553ac4

I am trying to make it look like this:

http://example.com/subfolder/menu/1/1/#/

But this code is causing the page to crash/not be found or something:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^a=([0-9]+)&b=([0-9]+)&token=([A-Za-z0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^subfolder/index.php /menu/$1/$2/#? [R=301,L]
```

I put this `.htaccess` file in my root folder `example.com/.htaccess`, do I need to put it in the subfolder?

I'm getting 404 page not found error !

Comment: I think you need to use `$1` and `$2`, not `%1` and `%2`...

Comment: @minitech Oops that was a mistake... but I still get the same problem. Any other idea?

Comment: Also, you can't add a `#`. That will comment the rest of the line. (The hash part isn't sent to the server anyway.)

Comment: @minitech I've seen other PHP sites that have a # though? Can't I escape it?

Comment: @minitech Nvm, I took out the # and still getting 404 error :(

Comment: there is a RewriteBase command to set the destination directory for rewrites to occur, maybe set that to your subfolder

Comment: Just in case you would like to know the way of debugging the rewrite_module, you can set LogLevel DEBUG in httpd.conf, then you can check on the apache error log.

Comment: @Hajo I tried `RewriteBase subfolder` but I got this error (RewriteBase: argument is not a valid URL) and error 500

Comment: @Ozzy see my comment to laurence's approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&token=$3 [L,QSA]
```

**Output: (http://example.com/subfolder/menu/1/1/#/)**

```
<?php 
print_r($_GET);
Array
(
    [a] => menu
    [b] => 1
    [token] => 1
)
?>
```

Or `http://example.com/subfolder/menu/1/18d519decbe60db44154b1fbc8c553ac4/#/`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2&token=$3 [L,QSA]
```

### UPDATE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?a=$2&b=$3&token=$4 [L,QSA]
```

Will match : `mysite.com/subfolder/menu/1/2/blah123`

and pass to `index.php?a=1&b=2&token=blah123`

### UPDATE 2 (as there is not subfolder - see comment):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/$ index.php?a=$3&b=$4&token=$5 [L,QSA]
```

Will match : `mysite.com/subfolder/menu/1/2/blah123`

and pass to `index.php?a=1&b=2&token=blah123`

**Please have a read of this site:** http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: Shouldn't [A-Za-z0-9]+ be the 3rd parameter though?

Comment: Well, with your code, my site works again, but nothing seems to change, my URL is still like before not changed. BTW in your print_r you got the wrong results... a = 1, b = 1, token = 8d519decbe60.....

Comment: Your urls wont dynamically change you need to adapt to the rewrite rule and echo out the url as you expect to use it.

Comment: The .htaccess goes in the scripts directory not the root, thats what the RewriteBase is for else you would need to add the subfolder to the beginning of the `RewriteRule ^subfolder/...`

Comment: I'm confused! I just want the URL to look nice, if the URL is like this: `index.php?a=1&b=2&token=blah123` I want it to show `mysite.com/subfolder/menu/1/2/blah123`, but I want it to still translate to `index.php?a=1&b=2&token=blah123` but show the pretty URL... is it possible?

Comment: Ok one sec, I confused the `#` with what you ment

Comment: Before, I wanted to show # instead of the token, but then I will lose the GET["token"] right? So now, I don't need the #

Comment: no your lose `menu` unless you pass it too a get parm, check the end bit. You cant pass a # through get its a hash or a page anchor http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Hmm... I used your updated code and still get Page Not Found: 404 error when I type this type of url `mysite.com/subfolder/menu/1/2/blah123` into the address bar. I don't understand whats wrong :/. Also, there is not script path :S I just have a root/ and inside there logfiles/ and htdocs/, htdocs/ is my web root where I have .htaccess

Comment: @Ozzy so there is no `subfolder` that contains your script, when talking rewrite there is no such thing as folders its just a route, ill update my answer again to include this

Comment: I'm really sorry for taking so much of your time! But I get the same problem! 404 error... there must be something else wrong :/. Is there a very simple rewrite-rule I can do to test it?

Comment: why not at the top of your index.php script add `print_r($_GET);
die;` then work from the top example and work your way down, thats how I originally tested the first rewrite to get that array. simple debugging. good luck

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I managed to get it working by putting the .htaccess one folder up & starting by a simple `RewriteRule index.php new.html` then I worked from that. Now I have a new problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10372178/rewriterule-works-but-ugly-url-shows-instead-of-pretty-one

Answer (score 1):

Don't you want to include 'subfolder' in the rewritten url?

RewriteRule ^subfolder/index.php /subfolder/menu/$1/$2/#? [R=301,L]

Comment: Probably! I don't really know what I'm doing here. Do I have to have a real folder 'menu' for it to work?