# RewriteRule works but ugly URL shows instead of pretty one

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /admin

RewriteRule menu/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+) http://www.mysite.com/admin/index.php?m=$1&o=$2&token=$3 [R,L]
```

I had to include the full URL because without it, it kept redirecting to `http://www.mysite.com/menu/1/1/login.php` instead of `mysite.com/admin/login.php`

So I rewrote my links, so that they look like this:

```
<a href="/admin/menu/1/1/bl4h1234">Some link</a>
```

And that works fine, but the URL shows in the address bar as the ugly URL, but the whole purpose was to show the URL as the pretty URL :/

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative *(& standard [MVC / Front controller Patterns])* way to handle mod_rewrite rules and rewriting is to pass the whole url to your index.php and then process it there.

It actually makes it simpler in the long run, otherwise the complexity of your problems will only increase as you add more features.

As it seems you are using folders `(menu|admin)` with an *index.php* in each, you have no kind of router script.
So you will need to handle the basic route in the `.htaccess`. You basically just need a rewrite for each folder.

The .htaccess goes in your root. Else you would need a rewrite for each folder and without the RewriteBase /path

**Directory Structure (Where to put the .htaccess, in root):**

```
ROOT>/
     /index.php
     /.htaccess
     /admin/
           /index.php
     /menu/
          /index.php
     /someOtherFolder/
                     /index.php
                     /somefile.php
```

**The .htaccess rewrite**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^admin/menu/(.*)$ admin/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^menu/(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then within your index.php files you handle the route, by exploding the `$_GET['route']` param by `/`

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['route'])){
    $url = explode('/',$_GET['route']);
    //Assign your variables, or whatever you name them
    $m     = $url[0];
    $o     = $url[1];
    $token = $url[2];
}else{
    $m     = null;
    $o     = null;
    $token = null;
}
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: np, dont give up it will pay off in the long run ;)

Comment: Yeah, I read that SEO stuff, apparently google treats diff params as different addresses so it lowers your ranks. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 1):

You are redirecting to the new URL via `[R]`.  Instead, remove the protocol and domain from the rewrite and lose the `[R]`. This will perform an internal rewrite.

```
RewriteRule menu/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+) index.php?m=$1&o=$2&token=$3 [L]
```

Comment: but without the protocol and domain it doesn't work because it tries to find `login.php` and finds the wrong address (see the note under my htaccess code). And I first did it without the 'R' flag but same problem (and I just double-checked this now).

Comment: @Ozzy what result do you get with my rule exactly as it currently is?

Comment: wow it worked :O! But I tried so many of these yday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368980/my-mod-rewrite-code-in-htaccess-caused-the-page-to-not-load/10369074#10369074) and they were not working. The only problem is it took so long to load that the CSS file didn't load...

Comment: @Ozzy is the CSS matching one of your other rules?

Comment: Now I get an error `This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at http://www.mysite.com/admin/menu/1/1/login.php` same problem as yday... I don't think its the CSS... It's my login script (you can see the code here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14215/is-this-admin-area-secure-enough-v2) at the bottom. Also I haven't written any other RewriteRules yet.

Comment: @Ozzy If you're going into a redirect loop, it is either due to some other htaccess rule that still has `[R]` or due to the PHP code. The worst this htaccess rule could do is 404.

Comment: I don't have any other htaccess rules yet... Basically, the `index.php` has an include file (`authenticate.php`), this `authenticate.php` redirects to `login.php` if the details were incorrect, and `login.php` posts back to the referer (`index.php`), but `login.php` isn't loading because its going to `/admin/menu/1/1/login.php` which is the wrong address

Comment: I don't know what to debug... it works perfectly without the htaccess Rules, I'm thinking just to drop the whole URL rewriting

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't create the rewrite to an absolute URL. Remove the protocol
   and the host name from the rewritten URL.
2. Don't use the R flag if you don't want redirection.